# Не получает значение через Binding Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть функция:

```cs
public void _HandleBillReceived(object sender, BillReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == BillRecievedStatus.Rejected)
    {
        LogOperation($"Bill {e.Bill.Description} rejected: {e.Exception?.Message}");
    }
    else if (e.Status == BillRecievedStatus.Accepted)
    {
        Billvalue += e.Bill.MoneyValue;
    }
}
```

Вызываю через `binding` в `textbox`, хочу при изменение `e.bill.MoneyValue` добавился в `Billvalue`.

добавляется значение, но подписка на обновление не происходит

Вот `Billvalue`:

```cs
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public int output;
public int Billvalue {
     get => output;
     set {
         output = value;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Billvalue)));
     }
}


public BillAcceptedForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Часть XAML

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="BillCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding BillValue}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="796" TextChanged="BillCount_TextChanged" Visibility="Visible" Height="50"/>
```

Хочу получить в textbox значение который получаю от e.Bill.MoneyValue.
Где я ошибся помогите пожалуйста.

```cs
    private void BillCount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                BillAccess.Text = BillCount.Text + " c.";
            }
```

Здесь я просто добавляю значение другому текстбоксу при изменение этого текстбокса.

```
**INotifyPropertyChanged я добавил в этой же формы. 
Функция тоже находится в этой форме**.
```

```cs
public partial class BillAcceptedForm : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
          {
                    public BillAcceptedForm()
                    {
                     InitializeComponent();
                     DataContext = this;
                    }
        ///
        ///здесь функция 
       /// 
           }
```

При наведении в Binding Billvalue пишет не найден контекст данных для привязки Billvalue

Comment: а где сама привязка то? `output` должен быть `private`

Comment: не вставляйте код в комментарий, редактируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: `{Binding Billvalue }` уберите лишний пробел, и покажите, а где этот текстбокс находится, прямо в дереве, или в шаблоне элемента коллекции, какой у него DataContext? x:Name зачем? обработчик события TextChanged зачем? Что в нем? Покажите код обработчика.

Comment: `BillCount.Text = ...` ломает привязку, так нельзя делать.

Comment: Как правильно сделать можете сказать ?

Comment: Как я могу сказать как сделать правильно, если вы даже не показали как сделано и не сказали, а что же все-таки надо сделать. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: На счет DataContext можете объяснить примерно.

Comment: Что объяснить? Вы обработчик свой BillCount_TextChanged покажете? Стоп, покажите еще сигнатуру класса, вы добавили интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Но я же не где не добавил BillCount.text =

Comment: Уберите обработчик сьбытия TextChanged вообще. Вы вместо него можете сделать привязку во втором блоке так же как в первом, но с форматированием для BillAccess `Text="{Binding Billvalue, StringFormat={0} с.}"`

Comment: Ну и у вас опечатка, в привязке `BillValue`, а свойство `Billvalue`, а должно быть одинаково.

Comment: Убрал обработчик, исправил опечатку, без изменении при наведении в binding Billvalue пишет не найден контекст данных для Billvalue

Comment: А работает при этом?

Comment: нет без изменении, через отладку вижу Billvalue получает значение нов текстбоке нету

Comment: В показанном коде кроме опечатки ошибок нет: либо показанный код не соответствует реальному, либо ошибка за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: Отправить исходник может я что то не вижу что вы можете видеть

Comment: Стоп, а `_HandleBillReceived` в UI потоке выполняется, или в рабочем? Если в рабочем, то попробуйте синхронизировать `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Billvalue += e.Bill.MoneyValue; });`

Comment: Отлично, спасибо огромное, заработал.